# Active auto correction like in iOS

Tags: ios, auto-correct

I'm pretty new from Android, just dumped my iOS device.

I find it pretty annoying with this feature missing that is auto correction and auto-complete.

In iOS whenever you misspell a word or type a keyboard key near the desired one, the system will automatically change it to the correct word unless demanded otherwise.

Also the auto complete contains hell of a bigger dictionary.

Do you know of a similar app/setting in Android? It takes me much more time to type in my Android.

Comment: Please take a look at this to see how to use OS version tags: [http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/868/1465](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/868/1465)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock keyboard (as well as most 3rd-party keyboard apps) has both auto-correct and auto-completion (a.k.a. "suggestions") built in.  Access the keyboard settings via Settings -> Language & input -> Android keyboard.  From there you can enable and fine-tune the auto correction and suggestion options.

Comment: I did play around with the settings but is not even getting close to the iOS auto correction and completion capabilities.

Comment: Try different 3rd-party keyboard replacement apps from Android Market...  I mean Google Play Store ;)  Some have better auto-correction and suggestion features than others.

Comment: You have no idea how much you save me (from throwing my phone to the wall).